# Xamarin forms with Android Binding (.jar)

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, jar, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

How can I use a .dll generated with Android Binding (.jar) from Xamarin Forms?

For example in this [Picasso android binding](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/binding-a-java-library/binding-a-jar/), I can successfully use the .dll in Xamarin.Android, but i do not know how to use it in Xamarin Forms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You cannot do that!**

`Xamarin.Forms` Bindings (.dll) and `Xamarin.Android` Bindings (.dll) do have the same extensions but they are not compatible with each other. Because your `Xamarin.Forms` project (PCL,.NetStandard or Shared Project) and your `Xamarin.Android` (Android Native) project are not the same and a `.dll` like any other extension is made for a particular target audience, in this case, the `Picasso.dll` you make can never target Xamarin.Forms directly.

What you can do is create a custom renderer that can use these native libraries in respective Android and iOS project. But making those renderer's will be a pain in themselves.

**Solution**

The Xamarin community in the current times is quite strong there are a lot of libraries available online which you can use to do what `Picasso` for example does.

There is an excellent Xamarin.Forms library that does what `Picasso` is used for, [FFImageLoading](https://github.com/luberda-molinet/FFImageLoading) by `daniel-luberda`.

The library is widely used by the community and is free and can be downloaded on [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.FFImageLoading/).

It is well documented and well maintained by the author so there are no worries when it comes to library maintenance.

I hope this helps you with/solves your query.

In case of questions feel free to revert.

Comment: Thank you. But the issue is that I have a custom TokenSDK on android and ios which i plan to access through Xamarn.Forms.
How can i achieve this?

Comment: Well for that you will have to use [Dependency Services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/dependency-service/introduction) to write native code for Android and iOS